# mod_rewrite query strings returning 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a custom URL like this:

```
website.com/show/?id=9999&n=page-name
```

I'm trying to come up with a rewrite rule to convert it to:

```
website.com/show/9999/page-name/
```

Note that this is a WordPress site and `/show/` is WP page name.

Here's the rules I'm using in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ /show/?id=$1 [R=301,NC,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is working; it rewrites `website.com/show/?id=9999` to `website.com/show/9999/`.

Then I modified the rule for the second query string:

```
RewriteRule ^show/(.*)/(.*)$ /show/?id=$1&n=$2 [R=301,NC,QSA]
```

But now `website.com/show/9999/page-name/` returns a 404 error. It works if I go to: `website.com/show/9999/?n=page-name`.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

The 404 problem [is now solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476765/65732).

However, now I need to redirect the old query string URL:

```
website.com/show/?id=9999&n=page-name
```

to the new SEO friendly URL:

```
website.com/show/9999/page-name
```

How do I setup that redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out... almost.

@sepehr is correct that WordPress is checking, not finding the page, and throwing a 404.  So I needed to use WordPress' own rewrite engine to define the rewrite rules so it recognizes what I'm doing.

So I added this to my WordPress theme's `functions.php` file:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'init_custom_rewrite' );

function init_custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 
        '^show/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',        
        'index.php?page_id=2382&id=$matches[1]&n=$matches[2]',        
        'top' 
    );
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars', 10, 1);

function my_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'id';
    $vars[] = 'n';
    return $vars;
}
```

Now the URL `website.com/show/9999/page-name` works correctly, not throwing a 404.

*<sub>However, now I need to redirect the old query string URL to this new one. See my [updated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456927).</sub>*

### Update

Here's the rewrite rule to redirect the old query string URLs to the new SEO friendly URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^/]*)&n=([^/]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^show/?$ /show\/%1\/%2\/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Great, well done! I'll update my answer to provide a new rule set to rewrite the old URL to the new one.

Comment: Well done. Just a few notes; You don't need those `[^/]` groups when matching against the querystring as it won't include one ever. Also, escaping `/` characters are not needed on the *substitution* argument of the `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^show/(\d+)/?([^/]*)/?$ /show/?id=$1&n=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Wordpress defaults:
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
## Results
# show/9999            => show/?id=9999&n=
# show/9999/           => show/?id=9999&n=
# show/9999/page-name  => show/?id=9999&n=page-name
# show/9999/page-name/ => show/?id=9999&n=page-name
```

As you see, when `page-name` is not available, there will be an empty `n` query string parameter. In your PHP script, instead of checking for the parameter presence using `isset()`, try using `empty()`.

One last note; The above rules do not redirect the request, it maps the request under the hood, so that the URL stays clean. If you need a redirect, just add a `R` flag.

#### 404

Even if you remove your custom rewrite rules, you'll get a 404 from WordPress. That's because, as you said, the rewrite target (`/show`) is a WordPress page and ultimately get mapped to the index.php file. Then, WordPress checks its database to see if it can find a page with that path or throws a 404 if it can't. Obviously, the latter is your case.

#### Update

Regarding [your recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476765/65732); To redirect the old URL to the new one, you need some rewrite rules along the lines of:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)(&n=)?(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^show/?$ /show/%1/%3 [R=301,QSD,L]

    # Wordpress default rules:
    # ...
</IfModule>
## Results
# show?id=9999              => show/9999
# show?id=9999&n=page-name  => show/9999/page-name
# show/?id=9999&n=page-name => show/9999/page-name
```

Don't use `[R=301]` until you're 100% sure that everything's working fine, as it's aggressively get cached by the browser.

Comment: This still returns a 404 error for `website.com/show/9999/page-name`. However I can access the page from `website.com/show/?id=9999&n=page-name`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even if you remove your URL rewriting rules, it will still return a 404 error. So, the 404 has nothing to do with the rewrite process. That's because you're relying on a WordPress page for rewrite target. WP checks its database to see if the page exists and throws a 404 because it doesn't. You can put a PHP file there and avoid WP completely if that's possible.

Comment: But `/show/9999/` isn't an existing page either, just like `/show/9999/page-name/`. So why does the former work and not the latter?   If `/show/9999/page-name` is remapped to `/show/?id=9999&n=page-name` and I can verify that URL is accessible, then why isn't it working?

Comment: I tried creating a `show` directory and put `index.php` file in there, but I still get a 404 when visiting `/show/9999/page-name`

Comment: I put that rewrite rule in htaccess, but it threw a 500 internal server error.  I came up with one that worked, see my answer.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Well done! You're welcome. BTW, it works without any issues on a vanilla 2.4 Apache installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below rule in to your .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^show/(.+)/(.+)$ show/?id=$1&n=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That still returns a 404 error for `website.com/show/9999/page-name/`.

It also breaks my PHP script `$_GET[id]`, so `website.com/show/9999/` doesn't even work.