# Apache 2.4 URL Rewrite: /server/?Server=ServerName to /server/ServerName

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to simply rewrite the URL to `/server/ServerName` from `/server/?Server=ServerName` so that the `ServerName` parameter is passed to PHP.

I current have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Server=([^&]+)
RewriteRule "^server/$" "/server/%1/?"
```

When attempting to view both `/server/ServerName` or `/server/?Server=ServerName` I get a 404 error.

Here is my rewrite log:

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /server/
pass through /server/
strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp64/www/server/ -> server/
applying pattern '^server/$' to uri 'server/'
RewriteCond: input='Server=ServerName' pattern='Server=([^&]+)' => matched
rewrite 'server/' -> '/server/ServerName/?'
split uri=/server/ServerName/? -> uri=/server/ServerName/, args=<none>
trying to replace prefix C:/wamp64/www/ with /
trying to replace context docroot C:/wamp64/www with context prefix 
internal redirect with /server/ServerName/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

At this point, I need a little direction because I'm frustrated and I feel like it's a simple thing I am missing.

I've attempted tweaks from:

- [mod_rewrite query strings returning 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456927/mod-rewrite-query-strings-returning-404)
- [Difference between $1 vs %1 in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654834/difference-between-1-vs-1-in-htaccess)
- [Why I get 404 not found with the .htaccess RewriteRule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623564/why-i-get-404-not-found-with-the-htaccess-rewriterule)
- Using examples from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html
- Referencing flags from https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/

I have also been interating on the rewrite code in attempts to see if it was actually rewriting.

Using the code below successfully rewrites the directory `/test2/` to `/server/?Server=ServerName` and the page loads fine so I know the module is active and functioning.

```
RewriteRule ^test2/$ /server/?Server=ServerName [PT,L,R=301]
```

Attempted this change with no luck. URL doesn't rewrite, but the page loads.
[Apache 2.4 .htaccess friendly URL rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241189/apache-2-4-htaccess-friendly-url-rewrite)

```
RewriteRule ^server/([^/\.]+)/?$ /server/?Server=$1? [L]
```

Comment: "rewrite the url to /server/ServerName from /server/?Server=ServerName" - it doesn't make sense to rewrite like that (it should be the other way round) - which may be where you are coming unstuck. However, `/server/?Server=ServerName` is also not a valid end point... I'm assuming `/server/` is a directory (directories don't accept requests) - what is the file that actually handles the request? What is the URL you are linking to?

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for the response. /server/ is the directory. Index.php is the file in the directory it would use. 

I'm trying to get localhost/server/ServerName to replace localhost/server/?Server=ServerName or localhost/server/index.php?Server=ServerName

Comment: Why are you trying to put the server name into a URL parameter to make it available to PHP when it is already available using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rewrite the URL to `/server/ServerName` from `/server/?Server=ServerName`:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Server=([^&]+)
> RewriteRule "^server/$" "/server/%1/?"
> ```

You seem to have this the wrong way round. You should be linking to `/server/ServerName` in your HTML source and therefore internally rewriting the request *from* `/server/ServerName` *to* `/server/index.php?Server=ServerName` (note the addition of `index.php`, as clarified in comments). `/server/index.php?Server=ServerName` is the underlying (hidden) file-path that actually handles the request.

Although you seem to have it about right in your last line...

> URL doesn't rewrite, but the page loads.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^server/([^/\.]+)/?$ /server/?Server=$1? [L]
> ```

The URL must be rewriting, otherwise the page would not load. There may be some confusion as to what a "rewrite" actually is. This does not change the URL. You do not use `.htaccess` to *change* the URL. You must change the URL manually in your HTML source - the URL you are linking to.

You can (optionally) implement an external "redirect" later if you wish - this does change the URL. But this is *only* to redirect search engines and 3rd parties that might have linked to or indexed the old URLs. So, this is for SEO, not to make your application "work".

So, in summary, in this order:

1. Change the URL in your HTML source so you are linking to URLs of the form `/server/ServerName`.
2. (OPTIONAL) If you are changing an existing URL structure then redirect any direct request to `/server/?Server=ServerName` (or `/server/index.php?Server=ServerName`) to `/server/ServerName` (the canonical URL).
3. Internally rewrite the request from `/server/ServerName` (the canonical URL / the URL you are linking to) to `/server/index.php?Server=ServerName` (the underlying file that handles the request).

In the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# (OPTIONAL) For SEO, if changing an existing URL structure...
# Redirect "/server/?Server=ServerName" to "/server/ServerName"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Server=([^&./]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^server/(index\.php)?$ /server/%1 [NE,R=301,L]

# Rewrite request from "/server/ServerName" to "/server/index.php?Server=ServerName"
RewriteRule ^server/([^/.]+)$ server/index.php?Server=$1 [END]
```

This assumes you are on Apache 2.4 in order to be able to use the `END` flag in the last rule. This avoids having to have an additional *condition* in the first rule that checks for a direct request, and not a "rewritten" request (to avoid a redirect loop).

In the first rule (the "redirect") the `index.php` part is optional. The `%1` backreference contains the value of the `Server` URL parameter captured in the preceding *condition*. The `Server` URL param must be non-empty and not contain dots or slashes (as per the regex you gave in the last rule), otherwise it is not redirected or rewritten. Note that a literal dot in a regex character class does not need to be backslash-escaped.

Note that I have assumed (as per your example) that the URL being requested does *not* end in a trailing slash (ie. `/server/ServerName` and not `/server/ServerName/`), so I have removed the optional `/?` at the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in the last rule. Although your log extract would appear to suggest otherwise? If you did need to allow both trailing slash and non-trailing slash URLs then this should be implemented as a separate "redirect" in order to canonicalise the URL, not as part of the "rewrite" that would otherwise promote duplicate content (the slashed and slashless URLs are different URLs).

Depending on the values you are expecting in the `Server` URL parameter value, the `NE` (`noescape`) flag may or may not be necessary. The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is already URL-encoded.

You do not need to use the `PT` (`passthrough`) flag in `.htaccess`, since that is the default behaviour in this context. (The `PT` flag is only relevant when using mod_rewrite in a *server* or *virtualhost* context.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It makes a lot more sense now and your changes are working. I'll make sure to read up more on the rewrite module so this doesn't continue to be a problem on my end.